# Tracking User Journeys with Flurry Anayltics

Tags: ios, reporting, analytics, flurry

I have an iOS App where a sequence of three events spread across three Pages constitute a single Journey.
I can log each page view and single events via flurry. 
**But can I log the entire sequence as a single event ?**

PS: I considered using timed events but didn't seem like the best fit.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to track the conversion of this particular journey. If yes, then this is definitely possible by creating a funnel of these three specific events. For more information on funnels please refer: http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/Overview/Lexicon/FunnelAnalysis

However, if you are trying to log this particular journey as one single event, then that also can be done. You need to flag all the three events/pages and create an event, which gets triggered/logged when all three flags are true.

If you need further details please reach out to us in support@flurry.com.

Thanks